# Parallel processing for function?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I've written a function in Python to calculate partial dependence. The function works, but I want to run it in parallel, as it could take time for some variables. Below is the code for the function.

```
def partial(model, DF, variable):
    df = DF.copy()
    if len(df[variable].unique()) <= 2:
        var = df[variable].sort_values().unique()
    else:
        intervals = (df[variable].max() - df[variable].min())/10
        var = np.arange(df[variable].min(), df[variable].max(), intervals)

    partial = pd.DataFrame({
        'variable': var,
        'yhat': np.zeros(len(var))
    })

    for i in range(0, len(var)):
        df[variable] = var[i]
        partial.loc[i, 'yhat'] = np.mean(model.predict_proba(df)[:,1])

    return partial
```

I can run the function normally as shown below, and it takes about 10 seconds to run.

```
start = time()
logTApartial = partial(xgbfit, pbrvarstrn, 'logtotal_assets')
end = time() - start
print(end)
10.342937231063843
```

However, when I try to the two ways below to parallelize computation, both result in the error `TypeError: partial() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'DF' and 'variable'`. How can this be fixed?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()
    pool.map(partial, [xgbfit, pbrvarstrn, 'logtotal_assets'])


from joblib import Parallel, delayed
results = Parallel(n_jobs=12, verbose=1)(map(delayed(partial), [xgbfit, pbrvarstrn, 'logtotal_assets']))
```

Comment: I'm not sure that `pool.map` will do what you want. The `map` function will attempt to invoke the function multiple times (in parallel). I think you want a single invocation of `partial` to take less time.

Comment: Yes, I meant that I ran each attempt of parallelizing separately. So `pool.map` was in a different cell than `results`.

Comment: I think we need to check what you think is parallelisable about calling `partial`. Can you tell us what you hope to happen?

Comment: I hope to parallize the for loop so it can run faster. Ideally `intervals` will be divided by something on the order of 1000, not 10, which makes `var` much larger. In that case the function will take too long to execute unless it's parallelized.

Comment: Are you talking about the `for` loop within the `partial` function?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Then you need to use `pool.map` within `partial`, not from the outside. You need to ask another question.

Comment: Ahh ok, I see. I'll give that a shot.